# The Functional Equation $ f \left( x ^ 2 \right) = f ( x ) ^ 2 $

Tags: functional-equations

Consider the following functional equation:
$$ f \left( x ^ 2 \right) = f ( x ) ^ 2 \text , $$
where $ f : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z $.

The only two solutions I could find so far are $ f ( x ) = 1 $ and $ f ( x ) = 0 $.

Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Please don't solve the question [...] it's an active competition problem and the poster of that question is trying to cheat on the USA national math olympiad. (edt)